# How to map a string (ID) to the creation of a new subclass object c++

Tags: c++, registry, factory

I've researched a lot but I can't seem to find anything that will actually work, or if its possible. What I need is an object factory or a registry I believe, I don't know how and no threads are really helping. They usually use ideas I'm not familiar with at all so it can be hard to follow.

In my example, I have a parent class called `Art` and a bunch of child classes of the types of `Art` (e.g. `FireBolt`). I want a user to be able to freely add a `FireBolt` object to their list of `Arts` without having to ever include the `FireBolt` object anywhere. So going through only the `Art` object, I need a way to create a new child class of `Art` and return it. The idea is that it will be like a console/god mode type deal where the user will be able to add anything they like at any given time. I know games like Skyrim have this ID system, I don't exactly know how to do it though.

I have tried to simply map a string to an Art* object (`std::map<std::string, Art*> artMap`), and use a function called `regArt(std::string ID, Art* art)`, but whenever I try to use this it returns the error "error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token". Additionally, I believe this will mean that everyone shares a single version of the `Art`, and in the game specification, `Art`'s can change mid game.

Please note, I have been linked to other threads that try to solve the same problem but I can't get them to work in my example. A lot of comments to the answer that simply say 'This does not work'.

Some probably useless code;

Art.h;

```
class Art {

    std::string name;
    int EPCost;
    int castTime;
    int AoESize;
    std::string ID;

public:
    Art(std::string n, int cp, int ct, int as):name(n), EPCost(cp), castTime(ct), AoESize(as) {}

    virtual ~Art() {}


    int getAoESize() {return AoESize;}

    std::string getName() {return name;}
    int getEPCost() {return EPCost;}

    virtual int getBaseDamage() = 0;
};
```

FireBolt.h;

```
class FireBolt:public Art {
    static const std::string name;
    static const int EPCost;
    static const int castTime;
    static const int AoESize;

public:
    FireBolt():Art(name, EPCost, castTime, AoESize) {}

    ~FireBolt() {}

    int getBaseDamage();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many many hours of playing around with things, I have something that is ok. I dont entirely think what I want to do is possible, or if it is I simply have no clue how. This is what I settled with though.

I made a new class called `ArtFactory` (undecided whether or not to just expand it to everything in the game i.e. equipment, attacks, ect) with the following header and source files;

ArtFactory.h;

```
#include "Arts.h"
#include "FireBolt.h"
#include <functional>

class ArtFactory {
    static std::map<std::string, std::function<Art*()>> artMap;
public:
    ArtFactory();

    static void loadArts();
    static Art* getNewArt(std::string ID) {return artMap.find(ID)->second();}
    static void regArt(std::string ID, std::function<Art*()> f) {artMap[ID] = f;}
};
```

This maps a string (ID) to a lambda function in a static map. The lambda function will simply return a new version of the `Art` we want if you put in the correct ID, thus allowing it make many of the same `Art`, meaning I don't every have to initialize an `ArtFactory` anywhere. I will need to #include every art I make in this file, which is unfortunate but I think it is necessary. If not, I WOULD LOVE A WAY TO NOT HAVE TO.

The source file, cpp file;

```
#include "ArtFactory.h"

std::map<std::string, std::function<Art*()>> ArtFactory::artMap;


ArtFactory::ArtFactory() {
    return;
}

void ArtFactory::loadArts() {
    artMap["001A"] = []() -> Art* {return new FireBolt();};
}
```

To then expand this, just copy the line in loadArts and replace the ID ("001A" in this case) with a new ID and the new class (`FireBolt()` in this case) with the new class.

What I dont like about this is, if I `#include "ArtFactory.h"` anywhere, I've also included every other art. This method does not eliminate the need to link to the other arts, and in fact does the opposite. In this game, certain characters/enemies start with certain arts/attacks and certain items carry these arts/attacks, so it'll just be better to include the specific art/attack I need instead of using this factory.

What it will be useful for is implementing a console/god mode, because I can now easily list every art available and it's ID, and return a new art. I sincerely hope this helps someone at some point. I was stuck on this problem for a long time and I couldn't find any good threads.